# Дублирование value c input c form в такую же form

Tags: javascript

Необходимо копировать `value` из `input name=[id]` и `name=[ssid]` в `form id ="addEntForm"` в такую же `form id ="addEntForm"` только в `div id="div2"`

Пытался попытка увенчалась провалом

```js
var x = $('#addEntForm input[name="id"]').val()
$('#div2 input[name="id"]').val(x);

var x = $('#addEntForm input[name="ssid"]').val()
$('#div2 input[name="ssid"]').val(x);
```

```html
<form method="post" id="addEntForm" style="margin:0px" name="addform" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="openery();return false;">
  <div id="div2">
    <input name="id" value=""> // вставить сюда
    <input name="a" value="14">
    <input name="ssid" value=""> // вставить сюда
    <input id="numi" value="1">
  </div>
</form>


<form method="post" id="addEntForm" style="margin:0px" name="addform" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="openery();return false;">
  <div>
    kjhkjh
  </div>
  <input name="id" value="55"> \\берем отсюда
  <input name="a" value="14">
  <input name="ssid" value="W4sdENxN"> \\берем отсюда
  <input id="numi" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: нашёл временное решение изменил ид первой формы

Comment: `id` **должен** быть уникальным на странице

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID не может совпадать с любым другим ID в одном пространстве DOM. Ошибки, обычно, браузеры не кидают, но поведение будет разным и уж точно неверным (или случайно верным, на уровне 'пальцем в небо').

```js
function $(s){return document.querySelector(s);} // Syntactic sugar

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => { // After loading the page, copy the value
  $('#to input[name="ssid"]').value = $('#from input[name="ssid"]').value; // Copy the 'ssid' value
  $('#to input[name="id"]').value = $('#from input[name="id"]').value; // Copy the 'id' value
});
```

```html
<form method="post" id="to" style="margin:0px" name="addform" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="openery();return false;">
  <div id="div2">
    <input name="id" value=""><!-- вставить сюда -->
    <input name="a" value="14">
    <input name="ssid" value=""><!-- вставить сюда -->
    <input id="numi" value="1">
  </div>
</form>


<form method="post" id="from" style="margin:0px" name="addform" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="openery();return false;">
  <div>
    kjhkjh
  </div>
  <input name="id" value="55"><!-- берем отсюда -->
  <input name="a" value="14">
  <input name="ssid" value="W4sdENxN"><!-- берем отсюда -->
  <input id="numi" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Проблема была в том что форма служит для добавления материала на сайт и ид ее менять нельзя было, немного повозившись пришел к офигеть простому решению, форма которая автоматически генерируется поместил в див с уникальным идом. и вуаля пару часов ламания мозга оказались не такими уже и марными наверно. по крайней мере пока искал как это так бы придумать много чего для себя узнал.